# Setting RF frequency by putting screwdriver into coil

Tags: rf, coil

I am working on a small FM transmitter circuit. I don't have a trimmer capacitor so I can't set the frequency.

I remember that when you put something like a screwdriver, the frequency changes when you move the screwdriver.
I tried putting a screwdriver into coil, but it didn't work.
What kind of "screwdriver" can make that frequency change?
[image: circuit diagram]
(I've removed connection between two pins of microphone)
(6 turns, 9mm coil diameter, 1mm copper diameter)


I hope I could explain it!

Solved: Thanks to @JRE, I needed a screwdriver made by a ferrous metal!

Comment: Schematic required?????

Comment: @LeonHeller I don't think so, I'm asking if putting a standard screwdriver in coil is gonna work or not?

Comment: (1) What is the trimmer capacitor for if not for adjusting the frequency? (2) Your question really seems to be, "Why is tuned frequency not changing when I put a screwdriver into the coil?" (3) You haven't provided any detail on the screwdriver or the coil so your question is unanswerable. Add a photo of the setup and screwdriver relative to coil. Add a part number and link to datasheet for the coil. (4) Use <enter> x 2 for paragraph break on this site.

Comment: @Transistor (1) It adjusts the frequency. (2) Yes, exactly. (3) copper 1mm diameter, 6 turns, coil has 9mm diameter. The screwdriver is a cheap one, I don't have any information on it. I'm asking that **does all screwdrivers make the same effect** (if so, my circuit has a problem), or only specific ones? Like, made from a different metal etc..

Comment: Putting a screwdriver close to a small inductor in an RF  circuit can change the inductance enough to change the resonance frequency.  Whether or not it will make a useable difference in your circuit depends on what the inductor is doing.  When I worked on two way radios, I had a screwdriver for doing the alignment that was made of ceramic and plastic so that it didn't mess up the tuning.

Comment: What happens to the inductance depends on the material of the screwdriver.  Ferrous metals will increase the inductance, which will lower the resonant frequency of the circuit.  Brass or aluminum (not many screwdrivers made of either of those) will lower the inductance, which increases the resonant frequency.

Comment: Post your circuit diagram, and indicate which inductor you are trying to tune.  Also, keep mind that if you do get the frequency adjusted that way, it will be difficult (read that as impossible) to keep it adjusted that way.

Comment: @JRE thank you! The keyword is "ferrous metals"! Yeah, I wasn't gonna "set" the frequency with the screwdriver, I was trying to see if circuit works, without a trimmer capacitor. Thank you so much! Circuit diagram: http://static.electro-tech-online.com/imgcache/2543-circuit3.jpg

Comment: Add the image inline in your question and add in the extra details we've tortured out of you. That way all the information is in the one place for anyone trying to help and we don't have to follow links.

Comment: ::Boggle:: Where did you get a non-ferrous screwdriver?

Comment: @JRE You know better than to post answers in comments. Your "helpful comments" solved the problem, but cannot be accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a beginner to electronics, this site and not perfect in English, so I do a lot of mistakes. Sorry! :D

Comment: @JRE just found it in my room, lol. I'm not sure if it's non-ferrous.

Comment: @pipe. I was trying to get to the source of the problem.  Posted an answer now that things are clear.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but a friend wired a coil around his coffee mug. It changes inductance depending on the amount of coffee in the mug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screwdrivers are usually made of ferrous metals (various steel alloys containing iron.)

As such, when brought near to or inserted in the interior of an air core inductor, they will increase the inductance of the coil.

Whether that will change the frequency of an oscillator (or in your case, transmitter) depends on what the coil is doing in the circuit.

If it is a choke to keep RF from going back out over the power supply, then changing its inductance won't change the transmitter frequency.

In the circuit you linked to (see below,) the inductor is part of the LC tank that sets the frequency of the oscillator.  Changing its inductance should noticeably change the frequency of the oscillator.

An alternative to poking a screwdriver into the core of the coil would be to add a loop to the coil (permanenly increasing its inductance.). Then you can tune the circuit by pushing the windings apart to lower the inductance.  Once you have where you want it, you just leave the (now slightly mashed) coil as it is and the frequency will stay (pretty much) set.

---

Variable inductors work in a couple of different ways.

Most variable inductors have a moveable slug of ferrite.  It has screw threads, and rotating it moves it into or out of the coil.  More of the slug in the coil is higher inductance.

I have also seen (and tuned) circuits in which the inductor had a brass slug as a core.  In these inductors, moving the slug into the coil would DECREASE the inductance.

That is the opposite of what you usually expect.

I have read that aluminum reacts much like brass, but I have never seen a variable inductor with an aluminum slug.

---

Here's the circuit that Cagri was trying to tune:

[image]

L1 is part of the LC tank that sets the frequency of the oscillator.